# Css- How can I achieve double color and different direction sloped border?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using clipth path but it will not work. How can I achieve this?

[image]

**Code:**

```css
.footer
{
background-color: #6bbbb1;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%,0% 100%,0% 0%,0 calc(100% - 6vw));
}

.inner
{
background: #1e557e;
clip-path: polygon(0 85%, 100% 65%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 85%);
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="inner">
   <div>Footer</div>
   <div>Footer menu</div>
   <div>Logo</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Please add some more information on what you want to achieve

Comment: @GarvPuri   I need a design same like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzDiE.png

Comment: @Srinivasan Maybe this site will help you [clip path generator](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/clip-path-generator)

Comment: @ShashankGb I was tried but two borders with different directions. So i confused like this design -  i.stack.imgur.com/jzDiE.png